# Does Mysqli_multi_query improve performance

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am updating mysql data through php script. I am looking to use mysqli_multi_query() instead of mysql_query. I have N number of update queries to execute. Please suggest if multi query will help in better execution time.

```
A. Updating data using mysql_query(), Firing single single queries N times.
B. Concatinating All Update queries with ";" and firing once using multi query.
```

Please Suggest if Technique "B" will help in performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you care about error handling in this scenario? Do you need to be able to verify the results of each individual query?

Comment: YMMV just test it yourself in your environment and go for the faster one

Comment: @Mike: No I don't want to verify results for each individual queries.

Answer (score 1):

C. Use prepared statements and if possible (InnoDB) within a transaction.

A multiquery will save you some client-server roundups, but the queries are still executed one by one.

If you use prepared statement together with transactions, the query is checked once by the parser after that just values are pasted to server. Transaction prevents indexes being rebuild after each update.

Multiple insert statements can be rewritten as a single bulk insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1,c2,c3) VALUES (1,2,3), (3,4,5) --etc
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking to execute multiple update queries every time on different tables. If I am choosing prepared statements then I have to prepare single query and execute. To execute multiple queries on diff table i have to repeat same for every query. So I feel prepare is not beneficial in this case. May be i am wrong .. Please suggest your thoughts.

Comment: It's hard to say, I can't imagine that you have 100 different queries in one script. But you're question is to general to give accurate answer. You'll need to find out yourself through benchmarking. And then decide if the performance gain (if any) outweighs loss of control